# Xamarin.Forms: "Unkown VS Wildcard Development" profile in IOS Bundle Signing CANNOT BUILD

Tags: ios

I set up my app in the developer console from ios. Gave it the same bundle ID as my project and set up multiple profiles. I now download those profiles on my mac and double click them - all that now happens, is that it opens xCode (which i dont use at all).

I close xCode and now I should set the ios Bundle signing to manual and then to "automatic". Now, in the next list I should have the profiles of the paired mac. Here it says "Unknown" VS Wildcard development or i can also chose "didnt find mathching profiles".

Now - where is this unknown thing comming from in this list?[image: VS WildCard Ve]

If I chose it like this and now try to build the app it fails with:

"NO IOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile VS Wildcard Development"

Where is this issue comming from and what can i DO?

THank you!

Answer (score 0):

Forget all you learned from the docs. Simply export the key file from mac (result must be .p12). and export it to visual studio

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem.  Could you elaborate on your answer?  A step-by-step procedure would be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to select Automatic for the Provisioning Profile (Bereitstellungsprofil).  My Signing Identity is the one for development that was set up on the apple developer site.